# $\min\{h(t),1\}$ represented as an algebraic expression

Tags: real-analysis

This function just blew my mind, how can it be derived?

$$min\,\{h(t),1\}=\frac{h(t)+1-|h(t)-1|}{2}\\
h(t)=\frac{1}{3}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}+1-|\frac{1}{3}-1|}{2}=\frac{\frac{4}{3}-\frac{2}{3}}{2}=\frac{2}{3*2}=\frac{1}{3}\\
h(t)=2=\frac{2+1-|2-1|}{2}=\frac{3-1}{2}=1$$

Comment: Just argue in cases depending on who's bigger.  It follows from how the absolute value behaves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arguing in cases (as Randall suggested in the comments) is the best formal way to go about proving that formula. But if you are looking for a more intuitive way, here is one approach:

Take two real numbers $a$ and $b$. The midpoint between them is at $\dfrac{a+b}{2}$. Also, since $|b-a|$ is the distance between $a$ and $b$, both of the numbers $a$ and $b$ are $\dfrac{|b-a|}{2}$ away from this midpoint. So to get to the smaller of $a$ and $b$, you need to start at $\dfrac{a+b}{2}$ and "go backward" by $\dfrac{|b-a|}{2}$. Thus, $\min\{a,b\} = \dfrac{a+b}{2} - \dfrac{|b-a|}{2}$. You can think in a similar manner to see that $\max\{a,b\} = \dfrac{a+b}{2} + \dfrac{|b-a|}{2}$.

Comment: Pretty nice.  +1